# Query with in a loop getting slower and slower

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a process that reads a data feed line by line, parses and inserts the data into a MyISAM table.  When it first start, it goes really quick, probably around 1000 records a second.  As time progresses it gets slower and slower, right now we're at about 1 rows every 180 seconds.

The general syntax of the function is:

```
function parse($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgets($fileHandle, 1000);
    switch (substr($line, 0, 2)) { //gets record type
      case '01' :
        //parse the record
        //escapes some strings with mysql_real_escape_string()
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO table VALUES ($a, $b, $c...');
      case '02' :
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

The current file being parsed has a few million records.  The server doesn't appear to be losing memory space.  Does anybody know what could be causing the process to slow down?

Comment: Is there an index on the table?  Index updating could be the culprit. Also, how often do you commit?

Comment: Do you have indexing on 'table' ?

Comment: @bensiu & @Jim Garrison - why would you need indexing for INSERT?

Comment: Also probably you should post use your schema?

Comment: @FeRtoll - you don't need an index for INSERTS, but if there is an index on the table when you do an INSERT the index must be rewritten to include the most recently inserted record - which would slow the insert process

Comment: There is only a primary key on an auto_increment column.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Why use MyISAM; it is going away in 8.0.

Comment: What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  It should be about 20% of _available_ RAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably has to do with having to write so frequently to your indexes. You are already using MyISAM which would be my first suggestion.

Some suggestions

1. Batch insert every 100 rows
2. Use INSERT DELAYED to allow MySQL to allow inserts to quickly finish queuing, and MySQL will insert the record when resources are more permitting.
3. Have your script create an SQL dump/delimited file which you can load using IN FILE importing functions, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html which will be MUCH FASTER than batch inserts

Comment: Thanks, I will try these.  There is only one index, a primary key on an auto increment column.

Comment: @ParrisVarney - The `INSERT` you gave is not compatible with having an `AUTO_INCREMENT` !  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have at least one index on this table.  So each row is getting inserted into an increasingly large index. Before you start your load, do

> ALTER TABLE table DISABLE KEYS

After you're done do

> ALTER TABLE table ENABLE KEYS

Re-enabling the keys may take a while.

Don't try to use the table while you're loading it.  Also, INSERT DELAYED may help.  But probably not if you're doing this table load on an otherwise quiet data base server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be runnning queries in transaction(it got speedup), preferable using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) because it is much safer. prepared statement in PDO are probably going to be faster, but at least safer because they are invulnerable to SQL-injections. That way is going to be much faster. I have an example ready with tags for you:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
);

function createTable($db) {
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tag TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)");
}

function insertData($db, $array) {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    foreach($array as $elm) {
        try {
            $placeholder = array($elm);
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES (?)");
            $stmt->execute($placeholder);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            /*** roll back the transaction if we fail ***/
            $db->rollback();
            /*** echo the sql statement and error message ***/
            echo $sql . '<br />' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    $db->commit();
}

$db = new PDO('sqlite:database/tags.sqlite3');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
//
createTable($db);
insertData($db, $array);
```

**P.S:** I would also like to point out that [InnoDB](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/) is probably going to be better.

Comment: MyISAM totally ignores transactions.

Comment: The data is coming from an internal feed, I'm not worried about SQL injections.  I don't think the version of Php I'm using supports PDO, but it could add ammo to my case to upgrade.  Does it do any optimizations that MySQL doesn't already do?

Comment: Wow you are using a PHP version before [PHP5.1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)? You should tell your admin you need PHP5.3 because without even doing anything you should get a [speed improvement of up to 30%](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/68-PHP-5.3-Up-to-30-performance-win.html). Prepared statements are precompiled so you should/could see a speed improvement.

Comment: @PMV I think that is a very smart thing :P.

Comment: And `mysql_*` interface has been removed in the latest release !