# Why does the SQL query in this loop get slower and slower?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, loops

I've got the following PHP code that runs this SQL query (on a table of about one million rows):

```
while (true) {
    $sql = '
        SELECT question_id, owner_id, has_answer, has_read
        FROM questions
        WHERE owner_id > 0 AND question_id > :question_id AND has_answer = 1
        ORDER BY question_id
        LIMIT 10000
    ';
    $questions = preparedQuery($sql, array('question_id' => $lastId));
    if (!count($questions)) break;

    $lastId = $questions[count($questions) - 1]['question_id'];

    // More stuff...
}
```

Initially, for the first 4 iterations it's relatively fast but from the 5th one it suddenly becomes incredibly slow. It goes from a few seconds in the first loops to several minutes from the 5th. What I don't understand is that the queries are all identical so I'd expect them to run at the same speed.

Any idea what could be causing this? Is there anything I can do to optimise this?

Comment: You're sure it's the SQL that gets slower? Is `question_id` the primary key of the table being queried?

Comment: Yes it's indeed the primary key and it's definitely this query that is slow.

Comment: It's probably how long it's taking the browser to produce the HTML the query is creating.  By what are you judging the slowdown?

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve with this loop?

Comment: I see that you want to iterate the 1 million record table with a 10000 step. is that what you want to achieve? did you search a memory leak in your code?

Comment: take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833445/query-with-in-a-loop-getting-slower-and-slower

Comment: I am nearly sure that is the Memory allocation and freeing. Enable Query Cache with type query_cache_type=2 (OnDemand) and change the query to **SELECT SQL_CACHE ....** and try again

Comment: About how many rows in the table?  Do most of the _later_ questions have `has_answer != 1`?  (This would explain the sluggishness.)  Consider adding `INDEX(has_answer, question_id)`.